# Data Concurrency within variable

Tags: r

I have data named as `my_data`. The amount of data is > 100000. Sample output is like below:

```
    id                      source
    8166923397733625478 happimobiles
    8166923397733625478 Springfit
    7301100145962413274 Duroflex
    6703062895304712434 happimobiles
    6897156268457025524 themrphone
    37564799155342281   Sangeetha Mobiles
    1159098248970201145 Sangeetha Mobiles
```

Link to entire data:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HUoRlVVf8EBedj1puXdgtTS6GGeFsXYqjVicUwbc5KE/edit#gid=0 for which I want the code to run.

I want a output where every id should be counted under source and also under which that is repeated
Ex ID ending with 5478 falls under both `happimobiles` and `springfit`. So `happimobiles` has id 8166923397733625478 and 6703062895304712434    which makes it 2 and 1 is common with `springfit`.

Output:

```
                   happimobiles   Springfit  Duroflex themrphone   Sangeetha    
happimobiles         2                1        0          0            0
Springfit            1                1        0          0            0
Duroflex             0                0        1          0            0  
themrphone           0                0        0          1            0
Sangeetha            0                0        0          0            2
```

I have also tried:

```
Pivot <- dcast(my_data,source~source,value.var = "id",function(x) length((x)))
```

which is giving me only unique records in specific partner correctly but not overlaps.

I also tried:

```
crossprod(table(my_data))
```

But this does not give correct answer.

Any other solution which can hep me get this kind of output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by a *self-join* and subsequent *reshaping*:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(my_data)[, source := forcats::fct_inorder(source)]
my_data[my_data, on = "id"][
  , dcast(.SD, source ~ i.source, value.var = "id")]
```

> ```
> Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'
>               source happimobiles Springfit Duroflex themrphone Sangeetha Mobiles
> 1:      happimobiles            2         1        0          0                 0
> 2:         Springfit            1         1        0          0                 0
> 3:          Duroflex            0         0        1          0                 0
> 4:        themrphone            0         0        0          1                 0
> 5: Sangeetha Mobiles            0         0        0          0                 2
> ```

The call to `forcats::fct_inorder()` is only required to reproduce OP's expected result where the columns are arranged in order of appearance instead of alphabetical order.

---

OP's production dataset with 10000 rows would produce a result of 85 columns when reshaped to wide format. Therefore, it might be more convenient to leave the data in long format:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr) # piping used to improve readability
googlesheets4::read_sheet(
  "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HUoRlVVf8EBedj1puXdgtTS6GGeFsXYqjVicUwbc5KE/edit#gid=0",
  col_types = "c") %>% 
  setDT() %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  .[., on = "FVID", allow.cartesian = TRUE] %>% 
  .[, .N, keyby = .(Partner, i.Partner)]
```

> ```
>                Partner          i.Partner    N
>  1:       AOSmithIndia       AOSmithIndia   21
>  2:       Adityavision       Adityavision    2
>  3:   BajajElectronics   BajajElectronics  128
>  4:   BajajElectronics   SangeethaMobiles    1
>  5:   BajajElectronics       happimobiles    3
>  6:               BigC               BigC   27
>  7:               BigC        BnewMobiles    1
>  8:               BigC             Celekt    2
>  9:               BigC         LotMobiles    2
> 10:               BigC   SangeethaMobiles   11
> 11:               BigC          Springfit    1
> 12:               BigC       happimobiles    3
> 13:           Bluestar           Bluestar   56
> 14:        BnewMobiles               BigC    1
> 15:        BnewMobiles        BnewMobiles   57
> 16:        BnewMobiles         LotMobiles    1
> 17:        BnewMobiles   SangeethaMobiles    2
> 18:             Celekt               BigC    2
> 19:             Celekt             Celekt   10
> 20:             Celekt         LotMobiles    1
> 21:             Celekt   SangeethaMobiles    1
> 22:             Celekt       happimobiles    1
> 23:     ChennaiMobiles     ChennaiMobiles   51
> 24:     ChennaiMobiles         LotMobiles    1
> 25:     ChennaiMobiles   SangeethaMobiles   12
> 26:     ChennaiMobiles            iPlanet    1
> 27:         Creaticity         Creaticity    7
> 28:           Duroflex           Duroflex   91
> 29:          EdunGruru          EdunGruru    2
> 30:       FirefoxBikes       FirefoxBikes   38
> 31:       Greateastern       Greateastern   12
> 32:                ICA                ICA   24
> 33:                 LG                 LG    2
> 34:         LotMobiles               BigC    2
> 35:         LotMobiles        BnewMobiles    1
> 36:         LotMobiles             Celekt    1
> 37:         LotMobiles     ChennaiMobiles    1
> 38:         LotMobiles         LotMobiles   30
> 39:         LotMobiles   SangeethaMobiles   14
> 40:         LotMobiles       happimobiles    3
> 41:  NarayanNethralaya  NarayanNethralaya    7
> 42:        NipponPaint        NipponPaint    4
> 43:              Onida              Onida   27
> 44:     PoorvikaMobile     PoorvikaMobile    2
> 45:           Richfeel           Richfeel   55
> 46:           Richfeel       VLCCWellness    1
> 47:           SKMobile           SKMobile    5
> 48:           SKMobile mobilewalavadodara    1
> 49:   SS_Communication   SS_Communication   11
> 50:   SS_Communication         themrphone    1
> 51:       SabkaDentist       SabkaDentist   48
> 52:   SangeethaMobiles   BajajElectronics    1
> 53:   SangeethaMobiles               BigC   11
> 54:   SangeethaMobiles        BnewMobiles    2
> 55:   SangeethaMobiles             Celekt    1
> 56:   SangeethaMobiles     ChennaiMobiles   12
> 57:   SangeethaMobiles         LotMobiles   14
> 58:   SangeethaMobiles   SangeethaMobiles 1060
> 59:   SangeethaMobiles       happimobiles   12
> 60:   SangeethaMobiles            iPlanet    1
> 61:          Springfit               BigC    1
> 62:          Springfit          Springfit  123
> 63:          Springfit       happimobiles    1
> 64:               TecQ               TecQ    2
> 65:           TheMaark           TheMaark   31
> 66:        TronxThings        TronxThings   14
> 67:      VLCCInstitute      VLCCInstitute   36
> 68:       VLCCWellness           Richfeel    1
> 69:       VLCCWellness       VLCCWellness   27
> 70:             VutsTV             VutsTV   12
> 71:       happimobiles   BajajElectronics    3
> 72:       happimobiles               BigC    3
> 73:       happimobiles             Celekt    1
> 74:       happimobiles         LotMobiles    3
> 75:       happimobiles   SangeethaMobiles   12
> 76:       happimobiles          Springfit    1
> 77:       happimobiles       happimobiles  474
> 78:            iPlanet     ChennaiMobiles    1
> 79:            iPlanet   SangeethaMobiles    1
> 80:            iPlanet            iPlanet   15
> 81: mobilewalavadodara           SKMobile    1
> 82: mobilewalavadodara mobilewalavadodara    3
> 83:        poojaratele        poojaratele   24
> 84:         themrphone   SS_Communication    1
> 85:         themrphone         themrphone   85
>                Partner          i.Partner    N
> ```

The steps are as follows:

1. Read the production dataset from Google Docs
2. Coerce to `data.table`
3. Remove duplicate entries (assuming that this is in line with OP's intention)
4. Perform self-join
5. Count number of overlapping (as well as non-overlapping) `FVID`s. Usage of `keyby =` requests the result to be ordered alphabetically.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about your logic, but hope this gives you some idea to move forward:

```
library(data.table)

# set as data.table
setDT(df)

# get counts by source
df = df[,.N,source]

# create a duplicate column (a trick to make dcast work)
df$source2 <- df$source

# convert shape using dcast
dcast(df, source ~ source2, value.var="N", fun.aggregate=sum)
```

Comment: df = df[,.N,source] this throws error                                                                       Error in drop && !has.j : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can get the unique source in the dataframe, use `lapply` find the `id`'s present and count their frequency using `table`.

```
unique_source <- unique(df$source)

cbind.data.frame(unique_source, do.call(rbind, lapply(unique_source, function(x) 
                table(df$source[df$id %in% df$id[df$source == x]]))))


#     unique_source Duroflex happimobiles SangeethaMobiles Springfit themrphone
#1     happimobiles        0            2                0         1          0
#2        Springfit        0            1                0         1          0
#3         Duroflex        1            0                0         0          0
#4       themrphone        0            0                0         0          1
#5 SangeethaMobiles        0            0                2         0          0
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(8166923397733625856, 8166923397733625856, 
7301100145962413056, 6703062895304712192, 6897156268457025536, 
37564799155342280, 1159098248970201088), source = structure(c(2L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Duroflex", "happimobiles", 
"SangeethaMobiles", "Springfit", "themrphone"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Hello Ronak when I run on these 100 records it does not work. Find the link to data set below

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HUoRlVVf8EBedj1puXdgtTS6GGeFsXYqjVicUwbc5KE/edit#gid=1854332553 I have added Ronak as new sheet

Answer (score 1):

I think you are already very close to what you are expecting when using `crossprod()`. Here is a base R solution, and you can try it

```
r <- crossprod(table(df)[,match(unique(df$source),colnames(table(df)))])
```

which gives

```
> r
                  source
source             happimobiles Springfit Duroflex themrphone SangeethaMobiles
  happimobiles                2         1        0          0                0
  Springfit                   1         1        0          0                0
  Duroflex                    0         0        1          0                0
  themrphone                  0         0        0          1                0
  SangeethaMobiles            0         0        0          0                2
```